# Lenevo Ideapad Wi-Fi drops frequently

Tags: wireless, lenovo, ideapad

I have Lenevo Ideapad 320-151KB laptop. When I installed Ubuntu 16.04, my touchpad was not working.

Then I updated my kernel to `4.13.2-041302-generic`. The touchpad started working, but now my Wi-Fi drops frequently (it was also dropping previously).

This is the description of my Wifi card:

[image: Terminal Output]

This is the output of `rfkill list all`:

```
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to disable the `ideapad_laptop` module that blocks your wireless adapter. You can do it by running

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ideapad.conf <<< "blacklist ideapad_laptop"
```

Reboot to apply.

Comment: I want to ask if I disable the ideapad_module then it will not effect my wireless setting on windows 10.

Comment: It doesn't affect anything on Windows. It is a linux kernel module.

Comment: The problem is still persistent and any other suggestion?. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is the output of command : sudo lspci -knn | grep Net -A3

Comment: 03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:8821]
 Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [17aa:a814]
 Kernel driver in use: rtl8821ae
 Kernel modules: rtl8821ae